# YAP initialization file?

Tags: prolog, yap

I am wondering if there is an equivalent of the SWI initialization file "~/.plrc" in YAP.
I would like to define some directories with: file_search_path/2 before loading YAP, but I do not know where to do it.

Any help will be highly appreciated!.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In my .yaprc

```
:- multifile(library_directory/1).
library_directory('~/ftp/Prolog-inedit').
```